# Xamarin ListView focused event wont fire

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm looking for a way to know if a Xamarin ListView has been focused, its property IsFocused and Focus event seems not working on android.
thank you.

Comment: "focus" doesn't have the same meaning on touch based interfaces as it does with traditional UI.  Generally in Xamarin "focus" means that the keyboard is active and sending input to the active element.  This does not apply to a LIstView

Comment: Does it has implementation replacement ?

Comment: See [ListView Interactivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity).